# Basic arithmetic operation on DateTime datatype in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: datetime, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer, smartcontracts

I have defined an DateTime datatype which stores the date of birthday of an Participant. Now i want to find the age of Participant,i.e., difference between the present date and his date of birthday.

Is there any way by which I can calculate the difference between DateTime in hyperledger composer playground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, its straightforward javascript.

Example:

model file:

```
asset Bank identified by id {
  o String id
  o DateTime date1
  o DateTime date2
}

transaction trxn {
  --> Bank bank
}
```

script file:

```
 // "date1": "2018-08-22T10:58:42.228Z",
 // "date2": "2018-08-23T10:58:42.228Z"

  var d1 = new Date(trxn.bank.date1.getTime());
  var d2 = new Date(trxn.bank.date2.getTime());
  var d3 = d2 - d1;   // in milliseconds

  var one_day=1000*60*60*24; // in ms
  var in_days_result = Math.round(d3/one_day);   // in days
```

given this - you should be able to work out how to do it in days, months, years using this example - and using the reference info here -> https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp